When i press edit profile i get value error
trying to make an edit page where you can upload a profile picture and add various things to your profile, but when i click on edit profile i get "ValueError at /profile/
The 'profile_image' attribute has no file associated with it."
models.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
class Profile(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  full_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null= True)
  designation = models.CharField(max_length=100, null= True)
  profile_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank = True, upload_to="static/images/")
  profile_summary = models.TextField(max_length=300, null= True)
  city = models.CharField(max_length=100, null= True)
  state = models.CharField(max_length=100, null= True)
  county = models.CharField(max_length=100, null= True)
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):  
  if created:
    Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
  instance.profile.save()

urls.py
from .views import HomeView, UserProfile, register, user_login, user_logout
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [
    path("", HomeView.as_view(),name="home-page"),
    path("profile/", UserProfile.as_view(), name="user-profile"),
    path("register/", register, name="register"),
    path("login/", user_login, name="login"),
    path("logout/", user_logout, name="logout"),

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
if settings.DEBUG:
  urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate, logout
from .forms import RegisterForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib import messages
from .models import Profile
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

class HomeView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, "home.html")

def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            return redirect("login")
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()
    return render(request, "register.html", {"form": form})

def user_login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AuthenticationForm(request, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
            password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect("home-page")
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password.")
    else:
        messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password.")
    form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request, "login.html", {"form": form})

def user_logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect("login")

class UserProfile(View):
    template_name = "profile.html"

    def get(self, request):
        try:
            user_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        except Profile.DoesNotExist:
            user_profile = None

        form_data = {
            "name": user_profile.full_name if user_profile else "",
            "email": request.user.email if user_profile else "",
            "designation": user_profile.designation if user_profile else "",
            "profile_image": user_profile.profile_image.url if user_profile else "",
            "profile_summary": user_profile.profile_summary if user_profile else "",
            "city": user_profile.city if user_profile else "",
            "country": user_profile.country if user_profile else "",
        }

        context = {
            "profile": user_profile,
            "form_data": form_data
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)

    def post(self, request):
        try:
            user_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        except Profile.DoesNotExist:
            user_profile = None

        uploaded_image = request.FILES.get("profile_image", None)
        if uploaded_image:
            user_profile.profile_image.save(uploaded_image.name, ContentFile(uploaded_image.read()))

        full_name = request.POST.get("name")
        email = request.POST.get("email")
        designation = request.POST.get("designation")
        profile_summary = request.POST.get("profile_summary")
        city = request.POST.get("city")
        state = request.POST.get("state")
        country = request.POST.get("country")

        if user_profile:
            user_profile.full_name = full_name
            user_profile.designation = designation
            user_profile.profile_summary = profile_summary
            user_profile.city = city
            user_profile.state = state
            user_profile.country = country
            user_profile.save()

            user_profile.user.email = email
            user_profile.user.save()

        return redirect("user-profile")

profile.html
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/profile.css' %}">

<div class="profile-page">
    <div class="profile-container">
        <div class="profile-container-pic">
            {% if request.user.profile.profile_image %}
            <img src="{{ request.user.profile.profile_image.url }}" alt="Profile Image">
            {% else %}
            <img src="{% static 'images/mypic.png' %}" alt="Default Image">
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <div class="profile-details">
            <h3>{{ request.user.profile.full_name }}</h3>
            <hr>
            <div class="text">
                <div class="email">
                    <img src="{% static 'images/email.png' %}" alt="">
                    <h5>{{ request.user.email }}</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="home">
                    <img src="{% static 'images/house.png' %}" alt="">
                    <h5>{{ request.user.profile.city }}, {{ request.user.profile.state }}, {{ request.user.profile.country }}</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="profile-form">
    <form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="{{ form_data.name }}" required>

        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="{{ form_data.email }}" required>

        <label for="profile_image">Profile Image:</label>
        <input type="file" id="profile_image" name="profile_image">

        <label for="profile_summary">Profile Summary:</label>
        <textarea id="profile_summary" name="profile_summary" rows="4" required>{{ form_data.profile_summary }}</textarea>

        <label for="city">City:</label>
        <input type="text" id="city" name="city" value="{{ form_data.city }}" required>

        <label for="state">State:</label>
        <input type="text" id="state" name="state" value="{{ form_data.state }}" required>

        <label for="country">Country:</label>
        <input type="text" id="country" name="country" value="{{ form_data.country }}" required>

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock content %}

The plan is for the edit page to allow you choose a profile picture but throws a ValueError instead.

Given you have null=True on your profile_image field user_profile.profile_image.url if user_profile else "" will give you that error when there is no image saved.
